# Laravel Eloquent - How Do You Add a Where Condition to a Distantly Related Model Using the ORM?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I currently have the following:

```
Cars::with('cases')->with(['parts', 'parts.engines', 'parts.engines.metals'])
                   ->orderBy('car_name', 'DESC')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
```

The above will list all rows in my `cars` table along with the metal associated with the engine in each of those cars.  The `metals` table is related to the `cars` table through the `parts` and then the `engines` tables.

I've tried using:

```
Cars::with('cases')->whereHas(['parts', 'parts.engines', 'parts.engines.metals'], function($query){
    $query->where('weight', '=', 45)
})->orderBy('car_name', 'DESC')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
```

But this errors out since `whereHas()` does not accept an array for its first parameter and I don't see a way to link to distant relationships with it.

How do I apply a WHERE conditional on a column in the `metals` table using the built-in ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whereHas()` only needs the name of the relationship for which you'd like to add the conditions. So, if you're trying to add the condition to the metals, you just need to restrict the `parts.engines.metals` relationship.

On a side note, when you eager load nested relationships, you don't need to also specify to load the intermediate relationship. That is, when you eager load `parts.engines`, you don't need to also eager load `parts`.

So, your query would look something like:

```
Cars::with(['cases', 'parts.engines.metals'])
    ->whereHas('parts.engines.metals', function($query) {
        $query->where('weight', '=', 45)
    })
    ->orderBy('car_name', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
```

This query will only retrieve cars that have a related metal with a weight of 45. Additionally, for those cars that are retrieved, it will also eager load all of the cases, parts, engines, and metals related to those cars.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean this:

```
Cars::with(['cases', 'parts', 'parts.engines', 'parts.engines.metals' => function($query){
$query->where('weight', '=', 45);
}])->orderBy('car_name', 'DESC')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Adding conditions to the eager loading will only restrict the metals that are eager loaded for all the cars. The OP wants to restrict the cars that are retrieved based on conditions of the related metals, which is where you'd use the `whereHas()` method.